# Calling abort() on Backbone model fetch

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've read that the return value from a Backbone model fetch statement is a jqXHR object, and that you should be able to abort it like so:

```
var xhr = myBackboneModel.fetch();
// ....
xhr.abort();
```

However, I get a 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function' error when trying to call abort. Inspecting xhr shows it contains a number of other methods (promise, resolve, fail, and a lot more) but no abort.

I'm using Backbone 1.1.0. Any idea what could cause this...?

Comment: can you show code? Cause looks like all right ( Also the questron - do you use jquery ? or other library ? )

Comment: I think you're right, Vasil. Looks like some other code running in the system that's messing it up. It's a big system so hard to identify.

Comment: you can find me in skype - if i can have access to your site or your can share with team viewer - we can try to find reason